# ChildrenAsTriggers

Tags: asp.net

what is the use of ChildrenAsTriggers in updatepanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx) for details.  The setting controls whether postbacks from child controls will trigger the UpdatePanel to update.  The default is true, but the page lists an example scenario where you might want it to be false:

> A scenario where you might set
>   ChildrenAsTriggers to false is when
>   you have two UpdatePanel controls and
>   you want a postback from the first
>   panel to update the content of the
>   second panel but not update its own
>   content. For example, the first panel
>   might be a list of products to buy and
>   the second panel might be a shopping
>   cart.